# Programmatically set Store View locale

Tags: store-view, locale

How do I **programmatically** set the locale information of a store view?

[image]

I don't know how to set this value, although I can get it using:

```
echo Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $store_view->getId()) ;
```

Here it follows the code I use to programmatically create the store view:

```
$store_view = Mage::getModel('core/store');
$store_view->setCode($english_store_code)
                    ->setWebsiteId($storeGroup->getWebsiteId())
                    ->setGroupId($storeGroup->getId())
                    ->setName('English')
                    ->setIsActive(1)
                    ->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('general/locale/code', $value, $scope, $scopeId);
```

See function definition of `saveConfig()` at `\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php`

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the code I used:   Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('general/locale/code', "en_US", "stores", $english_store->getId());

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code to set locale value. and write second line for clear cache.

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('general/locale/code','en_US');
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('config');
```

Please specify store ID if you have multi store.

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('general/locale/code','en_US','stores',$store_view->getId());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set Direct Language code

```
$locale = 'nl_NL';
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyLang($langCode);
$locale = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyLang();


Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale($locale)->init('frontend', true);

$defaultStore = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($defaultStore);
Mage::app()->getLocale()->setLocale($locale);
Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init('frontend', true);

$defaultLocale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();
```

now Site translate in Your set Language.

you can pass `$locale` value dynamically on dropdown change event using js.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();
$config -> saveConfig('general/locale/code', $value , 'default', $storeId);
```

Comment: $config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config(); .. this is not the best way of coding .. you should use Mage::getModel('core/config') instead..

Comment: Oh thanx for the information... But this is also working for me.